# How do I use the inherited method "generate texture" in Pixi JS from PIXI.extras.TilingSprite?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, pixi.js

I am trying to follow the Learn Pixi JS book but many of the methods do not work because the author used Pixi vs 3.0.0 and I am using 3.0.9 because the older version is not available for download anymore. It wanted me to user a Rectangle object to organise me tile sheet, but Pixi wasn't having any of that. So I heard about the "generate texture" method in PIXI.extrast.TilingSprite but I am having trouble calling it. So how do I use it?

Below is the code I have tried:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Attempt</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="pixi.js">       </script>

        <script>


              renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1200, 800 );

            //);

            // Add the canvas to the HTML document
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

            // Create a container object called the 'stage'
            var stage = new PIXI.Container();


            var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("images/png/Tiles/Tile1.png");





            setup();
            function setup() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame(setup);


                 var newtile = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.generateTexture(3,2,renderer);



                // Position the sprite on the canvas
                newtile.x = 0;
                newtile.y = 0;

                //Scale the sprite up so it's 3 times bigger than the original image
                newtile.scale.set(0.3, 0.3);

                //Add the sprite to the stage
                stage.addChild(newtile);

                //Render the stage 
                renderer.render(stage);
            }






        </script>

        <style>* {padding: 0; margin: 0}</style>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to know how to use the generate texture method, but if anyone has alternative practises so I can place my tile map that would be helpful too. Any one up for the challenge? I presume placing each tile one by one with the appropriate co-ordinates would be a bad idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm having trouble calling it"? Are you seeing an error? If so what error? Are you not getting the expected results? If so what results do you expect and how do they differ?

Comment: Sorry. I should have been clearer about the error. Here is what I'm getting from the Google inspect tool: "TypeError: PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.generateTexture is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

We're lacking some details about exactly what's going wrong here, but right away it's obvious that you're misusing TilingSprite.

Read up on the [official Pixi.js documentation](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.html) a bit.

In short, generateTexture is not a static method. "Static" means that you can call the method without instantiating the class first. Note that the documentation indicates if a method is "static" or "inherited" next to its name.

You need to create an instance of TilingSprite first, *and then* call the generateTexture method on that object, which returns a PIXI.Texture (the generated texture.) Again, this is all outlined explicitly in the documentation - it takes some practice to be able to parse docs like this but it is an essential skill to have when you're using other people's libraries.

Do something like this:

```
var sprite = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(texture, textureWidth, textureHeight);
var generatedTexture = sprite.generateTexture(renderer, resolution, scaleMode);
```

I'm scratching my head a bit as to why you'd want to create a sprite from a texture... and then turn around and generate a texture from the sprite. I guess you have your reasons?

Comment: If I'm honest I don't really know what I'm doing. Understanding documentation is still new to me which is why I really appreciated advice from forums like stackoverflow. As for the creating a sprite from a texture or whatever, I really have no idea what you're talking about. As I said I'm trying to follow the Learn Pixi JS book by Rex van der Spuy but hardly any of the code is working. I'm just trying to figure out how to create a tilesheet for a level in a game.

Comment: Sadly I don't have any tutorial recommendations for Pixi.js specifically, but looking at their examples ( http://pixijs.github.io/examples/ ) can be very helpful. They focus on a single concept and are very short and simple, so if you can figure out what's going on in those it will be a good start.